# Custom Bottom Bar transition to another view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar, ios10

So, I've made a custom bottom bar with UIButton's. Now I am trying to replicate the fade in transition so when you click one of the buttons from the bottom bar will send to another view controller and show that view. I managed to do that but my navigation bar it's not a custom one and whenever I switch the views, the main view goes under the navigation bar.

I am using this code:

```
//MARK: Main view
func yourFoodGoalAction() -> Bool {
    print("transition: YourFoodGoal")

    let nextViewController = YourFoodGoal()
    let toView = nextViewController.view

    UIView.transition(from: view!, to: toView!, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve]) { (true) in
        print("disolve")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.title = "Your Goal"
        })
    }

    return true
}
```

And to go back to the view (vice versa):

```
func selectedBarButtonAction() -> Bool {
        print("transition: YourFoodGoal")

        let nextViewController = YourFoodVC()
        let toView = nextViewController.view

        UIView.transition(from: view!, to: toView!, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve]) { (true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.navigationItem.title = "Today's Meals"
            })
        }

        return true
    }
```

What should I do so my views will not go under the navigation bar once I change between them? I do not want to use container view as every view will be custom. Everything it's being made programmatically.

Comment: how did you add the toolbar to the application? Because you should be able to add it as a subview to the main window. and it should be on top

Comment: The toolbar's a NSObject that it's being called through a function. It stay's on top. The problem is the navigation bar that remains there but my view it's going underneath it when I change views.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to illustrate the problem

Comment: just added one. Look at the 3rd image - starts ok but going back to the same one it's displaced. Unde the nav bar.

Comment: when constraining your custom nav bar to the navigationController.tabBar, how did you do that? Did you use topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor? It seems to top constraint is broken

Comment: it's constraint to the main view bottom anchor (view.bottomAnchor). Everything it's inside the view...apart from navigation controller which is independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I was calling the modal transition wrong. Modals go full screen with the main view. I just embedded the navigation when I am presenting the new view and call the modal from there:

```
func todaysMealsAction() {
    let yourFoodVC = YourFoodVC()
    yourFoodVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    let navBarOnModal: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourFoodVC)
    self.present(navBarOnModal, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```